# hibernate search 4 distinct results on lucene index

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

in a relational database there are some normalized tables, while the actually relevant data for me is stored in a view, which is really big (about 120 million rows for 80 columns).
About 10 of 80 columns are relevant for searching issues, which are to be implemented using hibernate search 4.3.2.
It seems logical to me, that by indexing the view entity and querying only 10 of 80 desired columns (@Field annotation) i'm getting loads of redundant data, which distincts only by the primary key.

Currently i do following:

```
ScrollableResults ids = fullTextSession.createCriteria(clazz)
            .addOrder(Order.asc("id"))
            .add(Restrictions.ilike(field, query))
            .add(Projections.distinct(Projections.id()))
            .setProjection((Projections.distinct(Projections.id())))
            .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

while (ids.next()) {
        ScrollableResults redundantResults = fullTextSession.createCriteria(clazz)
                .add(Restrictions.idEq(ids.get(0)))
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("name"))
                        .add(Projections.property("city"))
                        .add(Projections.property("postal"))
                )
                .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
        if (redundantResults.next())
            results.add((String) redundantResults.get(0));
    }
```

I know i must be somewhere wrong, my intentions are:
1. Get a distinct set of objects, matching my search criteria
2. Obtain them only using lucene index, since a DB-query is too expensive

While the step of obtaining the distinct ids seems to be really good at performance, the second step of getting the properties data from the document is really slow. It seems to me, that no queries to DB are made during both steps, which accords to my intention.
I think that projections are the only way to work on lucene index and avoid hibernate queries to DB, or am i wrong?

I appreciate any advice how to achieve better search performance.